# == and .equals() not working in java

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, package-managers

So I was trying to compare the string in PackageInfo and ApplicationInfo and retrieve their package name in Android Studio.

```
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    List<PackageInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

            for (PackageInfo app : apps)
                for(ApplicationInfo packageInfo:packages)
                        String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
                        String sysName = app.packageName;

                        if (packageName != sysName)
                        {
                            Log.d("", "NOPE DOESNT MATCH");
                            break;
                        }
                        if (packageName.equals(sysName.toString())) ;
                        {
                            Log.d("", "IT MATCHES");
                        //do something after that
```

So the problem came by when I saw inside the debug mode, they actually HAD the same string

Example in debug mode :

```
com.android.quicksearchbox

com.android.quicksearchbox
```

It returns as "**NOPE DOESNT MATCH**"

I'm really curious why this will happen and I have tried other form like trim to take off away white spaces between and no, it still does not return me "IT MATCHES", can anyone help please?

Thanks.

Comment: != you are actually comparing the reference which might be different

Answer (score 1):

Replace: `if (packageName != sysName)`

With: `if (!packageName.equals(sysName.toString()))`

Also, you have a `;` at the end of `if` which shouldn't be there. (Here: `if (packageName.equals(sysName.toString())) ;`)

Actually, to form your condition better, you should have an `if-else` block instead of 2 `if`s.

something like:

```
if (packageName.equals(sysName.toString())){
    Log.d("", "IT MATCHES");
} else {
    Log.d("", "NOPE DOESNT MATCH");
}
```