# ResultSet data comparison to String in java

Tags: java, db2

Im trying to make a conditional statement in my java GUI program. I was already able to make connection with my database db2 and also able to execute query to obtain a result set.

The problem is that when i use a table data to compare with a string in a conditional statement (if), It always returns false and goes to else clause even though the data from the resultset is identical to the string im comparing it to.

I have written the code below.

```
String query3 ="select * from module where uname='ADMIN' and modulename='SETADMIN'";
                PreparedStatement pst2 = conn.prepareStatement(query3);
                ResultSet rs2=pst2.executeQuery();
                rs2.next();
                if (rs2.getString(1)=="ADMIN"){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "if statement working");
                }
                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "if statement not working");
                }
```

the resultset that will be obtained by the query would look like this

```
**UNAME   MODULENAME    CANADD   CANEDIT   CANDELETE**
  ADMIN     SETADMIN       T        T           T
```

everything else in the program seems fine except for the if clause always returning false and going straight to else clause

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: try if(rs2.getString(1).equals("ADMIN")

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Not quite a duplicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong `if (rs2.getString(1)=="ADMIN"){` and is not working because you are comparing the references and not the content of the objects...

instead do `"ADMIN".equals(rs2.getString(1))` and take a look at this [post/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899879/and-equals-not-working-in-android-studio-java/35899981#35899981) if you want to learn why "**==**" is not  the right way for comparing objects...

Comment: The other thing to consider is that the data in DB2 may be a fixed length character data instead of a variable length string.  You may be getting back '`ADMIN      '` and not `'ADMIN'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare one string with another one, then always use this if other functions are always returning false:

```
if (rs2.getString(1).compareTo("ADMIN")==0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "if statement working");
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
rs2.getString(1).equals("ADMIN")
```

or

```
"ADMIN".equals(rs2.getString(1))
```

The latter is better because `getString` might return null.